# How to properly report Blender 2.8 crash and what files to send?

Tags: error

I experience all of a sudden crash of Blender 2.8. I am actually doing nothing and it closes.
I would like to report it properly.
Could you tell what and what do I send?
Where are crash related files?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender can open the [bug report page](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/) for you, and with 2.80 it also automatically fills in the blender build info and operating system data for you. Then you just have to fill in the details of what happened and how it can be reproduced.

Note that random crashes that can't be reproduced would be impossible for a developer to find and fix. The easier it is for a developer to make blender crash, the easier it is to find what is causing it. The more info you can give, including a sample file that can make getting the error easier, the easier it is for the developers to fix.

While the position may change over time, you can find *Report a Bug* in blenders Help menu.

[image: report a bug menu item]

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. Thanks!!!