# Blender 2.8 Eevee transparent BSDF leaving extruded text unfaced

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine, text-object

I'm trying an animation in Blender 2.8 (most current release as of 20 Jun 19, although the last couple of releases also do this) which fades up pre-extruded text part way through; I'm running Transparent BSDF and Principled BSDF* nodes through a Mixer node and keyframing the Mixer fac setting to adjust transparency. The text is extruded using the **Text Geometry Extrude** setting.

Using Eevee, I'm finding that, while the extruded sides of the text are fine, the front face is missing; when viewed from the reverse, the rear face is missing, however **Fill Mode** is set to **Both**.
The effect is not present in Cycles. (No, I don't want to wait for 160-odd frames to render under Cycles!)

Any ideas, please, if this is a 2.8/Eevee problem and/or if there is a way to get around the difficulty? (Apart from rendering in Cycles, of course).

[image]

*Diffuse BSDF also has the same problem.

[image: Blender 2.8 Eevee extruded text]

[image: Node Settings]

Comment: Have you checked the normals on your geometry? Else this just might be an Eevee shortcoming

Comment: I'll check when this render finishes (at least 6x longer in cycles), but I'm at a loss to see why the normals wouldn't be as you'd hope as this is a really simple 'add text/choose font/extrude/add materials' sequence with no mods.
Any chance you can check the process at your end?

Comment: I think extruding in negative normal might cause such a thing, but then the sides would be off as well... Maybe you can upload your file to have other people take a look. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Converted text to mesh, checked normals: they look ok to me, appearing from the centre of invisible faces. Test file link should be in the question now.

Comment: This is a bug related to text and curve objects, a curve with bevel and extrude values [has a similar issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfqyn.jpg) with a semi-transparent material in evee. You should [submit this as a bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140955/935).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @sambler. Logged under "Extruded text with transparent BSDF node loses viewed face in Eevee"

Comment: Actually I got in a bit early saying it looks like a bug, it is the show backface option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a transparent material in EVEE we need to set the materials blend mode to alpha blend. When this is enabled the same time as show backface, the alpha of each face gets multiplied and makes the backfaces appear more prominent.

You need to turn off Show Backfaces in the material settings.

[image: material with and without show backfaces]

You also get a similar result with show backfaces when the blend mode is set to additive.