# UV Wrap seen through object [EEVEE]

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine

Apologies, I'm not entierly sure how to the title this post without it being super long.

But to summerize, I use blender for my day job, doing artwork mockups on products, and eevee has sped up this process 10fold compare to waiting for cycles renders, but one crucial thing i'm missing at the moment is to see the back side of my UV Wrap on a transparent/glass object in eevee, I've searched high and low but can't seem to find any answers, is it currently possibly with how eevee is right now?

If so please help me correct my setup to show this.

Node setup is not mine, I found it elsewhere, but currently gives the most accurate real world result to what i'm mocking up.

Images below:

[image: Nodes]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is not in the shader nodes. EEVEE doesn't support hollow transparent objects because it's a game render engine. So this would be probably works with a flat window glass, but not with a cup. Every hollow glass object will appear like a solid object.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143774/935) may be relevant for you. The eevee [sorting problem](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#sorting-problem) in the manual may also help explain a bit more. Basically you want backface turned off for transparencies but that hides what you expect to see. Maybe unwrap so that the back of the glass gets the mirror of the front image.

Comment: Also, don't confuse textures with coordinates. Coordinates (such as UVs) are not the texture, they just describe the way the texture is projected on the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sambler's reponse spured me on the mess around with things something, and i've managed to 'fake' the transparency I guess.

Firstly I changed the blend mode to Multiply with Show Backface ticked.

[image]

With this though, the artwork shown on the backside of the cup was at max brightness (for lack of better words) which isn't what I want, nor realistic.

[image]

So I duplicated my material, and applied to the back half of the back, and shoved a colorramp node inbetween the image texture and diffuse node with a mid-ish grey which muted the colour to be how it would look on a final product.

[image]

Here is my complete node setup in the hopes it helps anyone, it's a bit fiddly but it's doing the job.

[image]