# I get white squares in my final render (cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

Weird whiter parts are appearing on my final render

[image: weird laser swords]

My render settings are
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5nqQ.jpg

Comment: Hello :). This can sometimes happen with tile denoising enabled. Solution is to Denoise in Compositor. Please add an image of your render settings, otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/abcHsd4

Comment: @VaffelLord don't post additional information in the comments, instead [edit] your original  question and add it there

Comment: Hey :). It might be a bug related to combined GPU+CPU rendering. It was mentioned a few times before - [Why are these tiles appearing in my final rendered image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/145855/78972)

Comment: Beat me to it ;-) Suspected GPU issue. Try rendering with just CPU and see if that helps.

Comment: Hey :), when i turned my Ryzen 2600x off in optix the problem dissapeared thanks Jachym Michal