# Blender 2.8 crashes while compiling scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, error

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YuM6HSXsgGT4AAPLwjIRf5dwiOvu_RoA)I have a new Mac Book Pro - with 32 gig of ram plenty of disk space.  Every time I try to render a scene using cycles I get through 5-30 frames and blender crashes.  Any thoughts or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Share your blend file

Comment: I added a link above.  This blend file is about as simple as they come but the render still crashes.  I never had this problem in 2.79.  i9 processor 32 gig of ram.  I have reduced as many settings as I can think of but the scene always stops along the way.

Comment: @RSchuler the blend link you shared is not publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of situation is why it is often recommended that you render to an image sequence rather than to a video file. Once all frames have been rendered you can quickly convert the image sequence into a video format.

If blender crashes after 20 frames, then render 15 frames at a time. You could also use a script that will repeatedly start blender and render one (or 10) frame each time.

In the [output panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/output/settings.html#output-panel) you can enable placeholders and disable overwrite to get blender to only render frames that haven't been rendered yet, note that crashing in the middle of a render will leave the placeholder. This should allow it to continue rendering from where it was when it crashed.

When you have a blend file that causes blender to crash, consider submitting a [bug report](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140955/935) so that the developers can find why and find a fix for the next release.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity.  The output is rendered to an image sequence all out is PNG files.