# How to keep the point density cache clean for an animation

Tags: node-editor

I have a particle system, that is added as the source of the point density.
The problem I'm facing is that when trying to render it as an animation the point density cube around the particles sometimes renders as a solid volume scatter shader, that is not my purpose.

I tried to clear the cache by taking the animation to the starting point and pressing play, and then rendering. This solved the problem when trying to render one frame and it renders it as  a particle based point density, not a volume scatter cube.

Playing it from the beginning does not seem to help when trying to render several frames, and also did not help rendering it in sheep it.

What should I do to keep the point density cache clear so that it renders the particle point density and not the volume scatter cube ?

Comment: I’ve not tried to replicate it but the behaviour sounds like a bug. What version(s) of Blender have you tried this with? If it occurs at the latest daily build then can you put together a test case and report it to the developers? It might be something that can be quite easily fixed for the next release. Identifying and reporting bugs is a great way to contribute to the development as it helps resolve issues and make Blender more robust.

Comment: it´s blender version 2.91.0 , where do i report this bug to ? i think it might  appers because of somekind of complexity in my scene , should i send the scene as a test case ? how do i make a test case ,

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140955/29586 - you can report a bug directly from within Blender and it automatically captures versions, etc.
If the problem can be replicated with a small number of steps from the default scene, that's best  - but don't know how practical that is in your case. This allows a developer to easily replicate the problem without having to rely on loading any additional files.So the first step is to simplify the situation as much as possible to narrow it down to the simplest case that still shows the problem.

Comment: will do that...